# Foreign key and referential integrity

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I've been facing an issue while I'm using MySQL, here is the issue, I've been created two tables named `Persons` and `Orders`, the `Orders` table references the `Persons` table as the following query shown, I inserted values in the `Persons` table, however, I when I check the `Orders` table, I spot that the value of `PersonID` column of the `Persons` table doesn't include in the `PersonID` column of the `Orders` table

```
CREATE TABLE Persons 
(
    PersonID INT NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    AGE INT NOT NULL,
);


CREATE TABLE Orders 
(
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);
```

Comment: Sample data and desired output would help.

Comment: I don't get your point

Comment: you should alwqays take a look at the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Your question is really confused, and your comment to @Kazi's answer contradicts what you say in the question. I suggest you start again, and give sample data with an explanation of what you think is wrong about the data. It's unlikely that a mature, heavily-used DBMS like MySQL would be doing something wrong.

Comment: In this example, `Persons` is the 'parent', `Orders` is the 'child'. Because a 'parent' maybe has zero up to many 'children'. I'm not sure you understand which way round the terms apply.

Answer (score 0):

In foreign key relationship it's possible to have a value in master table but not in the foreign key column. But it's not possible to have a value in foreign key column of a detail table and not having it in master table.

If a `PersonId` is in the `Persons` table but not in `Orders` table then foreign key constraint won't raise any concern. But it will raise an error if you try to insert a `PersonId` into `Orders` table which is not available in `PersonId` column of `Persons` table.

Hope above discussions will help you to get your answer. Otherwise please share some sample data to clarify more.

Comment: my question is how to insert records in the parent table(s) and automatically those records inserted in the child table(s)

Comment: In parent table you don't have orderid and ordernumber. How you will get those? Please explain.

Comment: I've written above, assume that I have put a foreign column of the parent table in the child table, in other words, I've set up a foreign key column in the child table, however, when I insert records in the parent table, I check the child table to see if those records inserted in parent table were available in the child table, I didn't them, in addition, I've set up ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: You won't. It's not work like this. This foreign key only forbid you to insert any PersonId into Orders table which is not available in Persons table. Nothing else. It will not automatically insert any data into child table. If you want to insert data in both the table at same time then you need to execute two insert statements within a transaction context but in Parent table first.

Comment: @chu3la "my question is how to insert records in the parent table(s) and automatically those records inserted in the child table(s)" No, your question post says nothing about that. PS Clarify via edits, not comments. PS Basic questions are faqs. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.